# How to Bind to the same UDP port on multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, bsd

I have two network interfaces and am trying to bind to the same UDP port on both of them but I get an error when I try to bind to the second one, `EADDRINUSE`. When I bind to the sockets I pass a `sockaddr*` where I've setup the port and the unique IP address to use.

Do I have to use the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR`? Will this allow messages to be received on either socket or will they go to the socket that matches the IP address their bound to?

Comment: Can you show the code please? It's _very_ hard to say anything without seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) one socket to `INADDR_ANY` for [IPv4](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html) or to `in6addr_any` for [IPv6](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) (you don't have to, but that's the usual approach). That will make that single socket able to accept packets from all network interfaces on the box.

Then `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option will allow you to bind other sockets to *more specific* addresses, i.e. to individual interfaces, and same port.

Packets will be received on the socket that is bound to the address best matching the destination IP address of a given packet.

Comment: So, does 1 socket need to be created for 'any', and multiple sockets for the specific addresses?

Comment: You can just do one socket for all interfaces. That's easy. You only need different sockets if the processing/functionality is different, or you need to separate the applications (like in a hosting environment).